# Bootstrap - click icon to display info box under icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I apologise if there is has been asked before. I'm not really sure what is the term for the action I'm looking for, hence searching for it has proven to be difficult.

I have a grid of icons. When a user clicks on an icon, I want a dialog box to appear underneath the icon, with content I've written for that icon. (I had a basic drawing of this scenario drawn up, but I don't have enough rep to post an image)

0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0

So assume each of those "0" is an icon, I have a grid of 4x2 icons. Clicking on any icon in the first row will create a dialog box ([ _ _ _]), with unique content for each icon, pushing down the second row of icons. Kind of like a speech bubble appearing from underneath the icon.

0 0 0 0
[ _ _ _]
0 0 0 0

Clicking on an icon on the second row should make the grid looks like this:

0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
[ _ _ _]

At the moment, I have something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">
    <img src="...">
</div>

<div class="col-md-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">
    <img src="...">
</div>

<div class="col-md-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3">
    <img src="...">
</div>

<div class="col-md-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo4">
    <img src="...">
</div>

<div id="demo1" class="collapse">
    <p>
          Description belonging to the first icon
      </p>
</div>

<div id="demo2" class="collapse">
    <p>
        Description belonging to the second icon
   </p>
</div>
```

(etc)

There are two things (that I can see) with the outcome of this code. 
1. The location of the information boxes is hard-coded. If, on a smaller screen, I want to arrange the icons in rows of 3, this means the information boxes will be appearing in the wrong place.

And 2. At the moment, when I click to show the information box, the height of my page grows down a lot, the information appears, and then the height of the page snaps back up again, to what I expect it to be.

Another thing I should note, I want this information box to span the entire with of the containing div/parent div, so even though the images are in col-md-3, I want the information box to be col-md-12.

Edit: 
**What I have:** a "jumpy" way to collaspe/expand information boxes, where the location of this box is hardcoded, therefore the amount of icons in a "row" cannot change

**What I want:** an information box appears under a row of icons, regardless of amount of icons in a row, and the displaying of this box does not cause the page height to jump by a large amount, then snap back to the expected size.

An image of what I want: http://s3.postimg.org/fnhz2w4jn/icons.png

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: is the behavior you are describing what you have done and want to improve it, or what you looking for better solutions? Using tooltips would be a lot better imo, but if your description is what you are after we can see into it

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added a section to my question, to clarify what I have vs what I want to have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your information box div does not strictly need to appear inline and below, but rather if it can appear as overlay below the icon, check out using a [bootstrap popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers), in your case with placement="bottom".

You will need a simple adjustment in the CSS of the related popovers to achieve the required width.

This:

1. will eliminate your “jumpy” concerns
2. will work regardless of how many icons are used in each row
3. is a more contemporary in design and user experience
4. is a supported, out of the box and easy to code possible solution

Comment: Thank you for that. Popover looks like the way to go.